# What font used in the logo of a ROBLOX game?

Tags: logo, font-identification

i'm new here, what font it is used in RBLXWare's logo?
Image: [image]

I can't literally find the original font in all font identiers on the internet. So thanks if answered.

Comment: Maybe it's not a font. The letters could be designed especially for this logo. Can you find other words written with the same font?

Answer (score 3):

[The font is called "Slant" on FontZillion.](https://www.fontzillion.com/fonts/010bus/slant?utm_source=fontsquirrel.com&utm_medium=matcherator_link&utm_campaign=slant)

Answer (score 1):

It's entirely likely that it's a custom design. The giveaways are that there's a gradient fill, two outlines, and an associated graphic element in the same style.

There are many "gamer" fonts out there that you can use with free licenses, but a lot of them, including this one from RBLXWARE, breaks many traditional typeface design practices and principles.